# VS Code is not responding (Slow Startup and Unresponsive) even with extensions disabled

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code, crash

VScode has been crashing every time I open it, used to work perfectly before. Its extremely slow (25-35s) to start and is unresponsive immediately.

[Unresponsive&&SlowStartup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RDqe.png)

> The window is not responding
>
> You can reopen or close the window or keep waiting.

Already tried the following:

- Reinstalling
- Launching after disabling extensions
- Same problem with VS Code Insiders
- Restart
- Fresh Install with no extensions also doesn't seem to work.

None of it worked.

versions - code-1.77.0 & code-insiders-1.78.0

Comment: Have the same problem right now, but using Ubuntu. Not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is resolved if you put `code.exe` as an excluded file in McAfee real-time scanning (or whichever antivirus you're using).

The exe is generally found in windows at the location:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`

Answer (score 3):

The issue for the original asker of this question was caused by their McAfee AntiVirus and may be related to a recent update of it.

There is related discussion in this VS Code issue ticket: [VS Code too slow during startup after recent update #177570](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/177570) (reported for VS Code 1.76.2)

If you want to add exclusion rules, on Windows, a user install is located under `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code`, and a system install under `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin`.

In the McAfee UI, see My Protection > Real-Time Scanning > Excluded Files > Add File (add the VS Code binary).

Comment: This was the exact solution to my problem.  Cheers mate!