# Visual studio code taking more than 30 seconds to open and shows windows error that it isnt responding

Tags: visual-studio-code

I checked task manager, it shows this

[image: task manager processes]

Vs code takes about 30 seconds to load and within that time its just a blank screen, but the moment it does load it shows a window error message saying it isn't responding.

I checked other issues and went to settings, turning the enable preview on workbench editor in the settings to false and scanning the system in terminal (which said it fixed a couple files but issue still persisted). I uninstalled and reinstalled, updated windows and disabled all extensions that I had on vs code and tried opening it again but nothing worked. Not sure what to do now.

Comment: any antivirus on your machine? If so, which one?

Comment: (Ex. https://stackoverflow.com/q/75931344/11107541)

Answer (score 1):

You did try many solutions, try also following:

1. Run VS Code in safe mode: on `command prompt` type `code --disable-extensions --disable-gpu --disable-telemetry --safe`. This will launch VS Code with all extensions disabled. If this works, then the issue is related to `extensions`.
2. Reset VS Code Settings: `File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Reset Settings`. It should reset VS Code settings to default.
3. Clear VS Code Cache: In windows `%APPDATA%\Code` find and delete `Cache` and `CachedData` folders, then restart the editor

Comment: Apparently it was my antivirus (McAfee), I didn't think that would be a problem since it has been scanning my laptop for months with VS code on it, just weird that it started interfering only now. Thank you though!

Comment: @persauce Good to hear that you've found the solution! Please post your solution and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having **Mcafee** as your Anti-virus, then this might work for you. As it worked for me.
So open your anti-virus (Mcafee), head on to my **protection>Real Time scanning>Add file**.

Now select the file **C:\Users\ {User}\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code/code.exe**.

Note- Make sure that "Show hidden" option in file system is selected, otherwise "AppData" won't show up.

You can also refer this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQRoik6lk6c)