# VS code takes too much time to open and it also shows vs code on windows 8/windows server 2012 will stop receiving updates. why?

Tags: visual-studio-code

earlier vs code application work properly on my windows 11 system but now when i double click on it to open it take 30 sec to open completely. Whenever i open my vs code a message on top of the screen popped with content written "VS code on windows 8 /windows server 2012 will stop receiving update"

why this message shows on my system i have windows 11? and i tried all my levels like deleted app multiple times downloaded from google directly and also deleted all the files related to vs code present in app data by searching google "file related to vs code" the again i installed but again nothing happen.

to resolve this issue firstly i uninstalled this application again and again but nothing happens. then i deleted all the files related to the vs code and again downloaded from google but no any changes occurs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: any antivirus on your system? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75934004/11107541