# VS Code doesn't open on Windows and cannot uninstall/install either

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason, my VS Code (on Windows 10) has just spontaneously stopped working. I didn't restart my computer or install any updates or anything, it just stopped opening. `code` in the command line is not recognised as a command, and if I click on the desktop shortcut nothing happens.

- I have tried to run as administrator; doesn't change anything.
- I have closed every running process of Visual Studio in Task Manager and tried again; doesn't change anything
- I have tried to uninstall VS Code, but I'm told I can't because there are still VS Code processes running (but there doesn't seem to be any in Task Manager). For the same reason, I can't reinstall it either
- I have tried restarting the machine and doing all of these things again

Is there anything obvious I haven't yet tried? Is this something anyone else has experienced?

EDIT: Just to be clear, when I click on the shortcut or anything, it starts VS Code processes in Task Manager, but the app never actually opens (even if I run as administrator)

Comment: 1) re: "_code in the command line is not recognised as a command_" - exact error message please. 2) any antivirus? ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75934004/11107541)) 3) what version of VS Code did you have installed? 4) is this [a user or a system installation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows#_user-setup-versus-system-setup) (which)?

Comment: 1) this doesn't produce any output at all once I had reinstalled, 2) nothing other than Windows Defender, 3) 1.78, 4) I have tried both user and system installation and get the same problem in both