# VS Code not responding in windows 11, showing blank screen?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

The problem is that whenever I open the vs code it shows a blank white screen(for 10sec) and then a blank black screen.
All these things happen after I install some Themes extensions(i.e. one dark pro), but I don't know why.

[Firstly showing like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xAce.png)

[and then like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgFDq.png)

[windows specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFj2V.png)

I tried all the things I got from YouTube and other platforms, but it's not working.

I ran a troubleshot.
I disabled all the extensions(but not working), and then delete all of them.
Reinstall the vs code, the newest version for Windows 11.
I also tried --disable-gpu

after all, it's not working yet.
please help me to get a ride from this problem.

Comment: any antivirus? (if so, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75934004/11107541))