# vs code error it crash when open window not responding show

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, crash

when I open VS code application a crash occurs and shows window not responding how to fix this

I have disabled the extensions in VS Code, checked for Windows updates, reinstalled VS Code, and checked for updates for all extensions, but I am still getting an error when opening the program. Although an option to wait or close appears later, I want this problem to be fixed.

Comment: any antivirus? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75934004/11107541