# VS Code keeps freezing "The window is not responding" + turns main interface gray

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, crash, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-python

I'm doing extra EDA on a Jupyter Notebook after I built out a model because the models eval metrics aren't great. I created a new file within the same folder that way I could work on the same venv and stay in the same directory. The model file works completely fine and I was able to run it perfectly. With the EDA note book it keeps crashing on me. The main interface turns gray and the outputs don't show. I tried to disable extensions, uninstall/reinstall, worked from a new file, and restart. Below are links to issues that I've been facing, the first one is on a PC so resolution isn't for me. The second issue hasn't been resolved in over a year.

[similar issue 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75931344/vs-code-is-not-responding-slow-startup-and-unresponsive)
[similar issue 2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155242)

In the second issue there is a workaround:

```
@kevindany, @tengyuntian I was able to resolve this by exporting my .ipynb to a .py file, then converting the .py file back into a .ipynb.

Open the problem .ipynb
CTRL+SHIFT+P
Select Jupyter: Convert to Python Script
Open the .py file
Right click whitespace in the file and select Export Current File as Jupyter Notebook
```

But, this isn't an option for me for some reason 'Select Jupyter: Convert to Python Script'. Any help would be appreciated.

VS Code:
Version: 1.79.2 (Universal)
Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
Date: 2023-06-14T08:58:52.392Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.5.0

Python Kernal: 3.9.16

MacBook Ventura 13.4.1:
Chip: M2
Memory: 8 GB

Data:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 182152 entries, 0 to 182151
Data columns (total 29 columns):
dtypes: bool(6), datetime64ns, UTC, int64(3), object(18)
memory usage: 33.0+ MB